# ASP.NET Core app under IIS - can't stay logged in

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am nearly finished migrating an ASP.NET Core app from RC1 to 1.1.0. Everything is working great until I try to publish the app and host it in IIS.

In a debugger, or working directly from Kestrel, I have no problems. I can reach my site, login, and interact with it normally.

Under IIS, however, I can load the site and am correctly redirected to my login page, but despite logging in with the correct credentials, I am redirected back to the home page and am not logged in. I can repeat this cycle over and over - I am authenticating, but some part of the IIS/Core middleware isn't keeping me logged in.

My site is using ASP.NET Core Identity which is largely unchanged from the RC1 default VS project template.

AccountController:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var signInStatus = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if (signInStatus.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            return View(model);
        }


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't debug this, because the VS debugger hooks Kestrel, and when hosting natively from Kestrel this problem doesn't exist. I'm not able to attach my debugger to the running Kestrel process (that was launched by IIS) - I can get attached but my breakpoints will not attach.

I am certain that the method above is being called. If I enter an incorrect password, I do indeed see the "Invalid username and password" prompt. When I login "successfully", I am redirected to the original page. The problem is that after the redirect, I'm not logged in - the navbar still shows my Login button instead of the Logout button, and I can't interact with any authorized controllers.

I know this is a super vague question with little source, but I'm not sure where to even start with this one. I'm hoping someone might see what my problem is and point me in the right direction, or at least be able to suggest some steps I can take to isolate and try to debug the issue. Or, barring that, even some hints as to what information I can add to my question to give necessary details.

Thank you!

Comment: Are your sure your index page is not cached? May be you still seeing "old" version from anonymous user? Press Ctrl+F5 or add some querystring to request non-cached page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two starting points you can try:

1. Install the latest [Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) on your server.
2. Monitor and compare traffic between the working and broken systems after you click the login button. Are you getting the Identity authentication cookie returned on the broken system similar to the working one?

Comment: Bam! Good call about the cookies - in my case, my browser that pointed to the IIS site contained *two* auth cookies, and the first one (in cookie order) was NOT the expected one. I manually cleared those cookies and refreshed the page and was able to login! I'm not sure how I acquired those extra cookies, but problem solved - thank you!

Comment: You might want to check if you log in as a different user that it doesn't user your previous logged in user's cookie and authorization rights